# How to summarize requests by url with path parameters using Kusto

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql, url-parsing

I am trying to summarize API requests by url using Application Insights:

```
requests 
| summarize hits = count() by url  
| order by hits desc
```

some of the URLs have path parameters which I would like to ignore in the summary, so if the following urls are called:

```
https://foo.bar/api/v1/items/abc123/latest
https://foo.bar/api/v1/items/xyz789/latest
```

I would like them to be summarized together as

| url | hits |
| --- | --- |
| [https://foo.bar/api/v1/items/*/latest|](https://foo.bar/api/v1/items/*/latest%7C) 2 |  |

How should I modify my Kusto query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [regex_replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/replace-regex-function):

```
requests 
| extend  newUrl = replace_regex(url, @"items\/[a-zA-Z0-9]*\/latest", @"items\/\*\/latest")
| summarize hits = count() by newUrl  
| order by hits desc
```